# SOQL Registered Symbol ® in where clause does not return results

Tags: apex, soql

I have account name as XYZ®Test’s. I dont want duplicate records so when i add new account I check if it already exists using an SOQL query in apex.

> Select id from Account where Name='XYZ®Test’s'

It does not return any result and allows to create duplicate whereas I want to prevent that. I cannot get rid of the registered symbol.

Also I tried adding an external Id field which has the same value to prevent duplicate but it still allows to create duplicate accounts with that symbol.

Comment: i don't see this issue.  can you put more details, your complete code etc. You might have issue at some other place.

Comment: That query works in my sandbox?

Comment: Is the query running in a `with sharing` class?

Comment: You should probably use built-in duplicate management, rather than writing your own implementation of it in Apex. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: @MarkPond Actually I have few records coming from external system and I check the name and update if it already exists else create new. In this case it is always creating new because it does not consider string with registered symbol

Comment: @DavidReed The query does not even work in query editor or in anonymous code of developer console by System Admin login. Its not the problem of sharing.

Comment: Like @Kasper, I can't reproduce this issue. You should really share your code in your question. Since you're working with incoming integrated data, text encoding may also be an issue. ® is a multibyte character in UTF-8.

Comment: @snehakem I just copied and pasted your exact query in the query editor of the developer console and it works for me. It gives me the correct result as well. Maybe you could try this in a new sandbox or developer account and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Kasper I just updated my query. Its not the symbol its the apostrophe i have in the name. I realized after u told me that it worked for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce thinks that your query ends at the first closing quote. If you escape that quote than your query will work. This should work for you:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'XYZ®Test\'s'
```

You can read more about this at:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm

By the way. Your current query actually works. That is because you used this ` instead of ' as your second quotation mark.

Comment: Nice catch pal.  Everyone literally missed it.